# Shimano Ultegra Bottom bracket replacement with Dura-Ace

Tags: shimano, bottom-bracket, compatibility

The bottom bracket on my Van Nicholas Astraeus is a creaking when going up hills. It's already been tightened recently, yet seems to creek more and more lately - probably due to the mileage (many, many thousands of miles).

The bottom bracket is a Shimano Ultegra 6700 (SM-BB6700), I've been looking at upgrading the unit.  I have an existing Shimano Ultegra crankset, would a [Shimano Dura Ace 7900 Bottom Bracket](http://www.wiggle.co.uk/shimano-dura-ace-7900-bottom-bracket-cup-set/) be compatible with this setup?  I'm also looking at [Hope bottom brackets](http://www.wiggle.co.uk/hope-ceramic-bottom-bracket/), do ceramic bottom brackets last longer?  Or are they just smoother?

Answer (score 2):

Providing that is of the same type and size it will interchange. As an example hollow-tech II 10 speed BB30 English will interchange Dura-Ace, Ultegra, 105 will all fit. Ceramic bearings are sold as smoother hence less resistance, will you notice the difference? It is hard to say, but probable not except in your wallet.